# React not rerendering while state of useState hook is changing (Object.is = false)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React functional component using hooks. The component is based on two children:

1. First one is a table listing data (time series) where it is possible to select rows.
2. A chart where I intend to chart the selected rows of above table.

**The issue I'm facing is that while I select new rows, the chart part is updated. But it is not when I deselect rows.**

The components to be rendered are as follows:

```
const chart = (isChartLoading ? <div>Loading ...</div> :
    <TSChart
        initialRange={initialRange}
        channels={channels}
        style={style}
    />);

return (
    <div> {
        error ? (<div className="App-error"><p>{error}</p></div>) :
            (<div style={{maxWidth: '100%'}}>
                <TSTable
                    tsList={tsList}
                    onSelectTableRow={onSelectTableRow}
                />
            </div>)}
        {chart}
    </div>
)
```

And this is the hooks I'm using:

```
const [tsList, setTsList] = useState([]);
const [channels, setChannels] = useState({});
const [isChartLoading, setIsChartLoading] = useState(false);

const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    function fetchTsList() {
        axios.get(urlList)
            .then(result => setTsList(result.data))
            .catch(() => setError('Impossible to get TS list'));
    }

    fetchTsList()
}, []);
```

**The code managing row selection is the following one:**

```
function onSelectTableRow(rows) {
    const currentChannelsNames = Object.keys(channels);
    const selectedChannelsNames = rows.map(row => row.name);

    // Remove deselected channels from charted channels
    const deselectedChannelsNames = currentChannelsNames.filter(x => !selectedChannelsNames.includes(x));

    function removeDeselectedChannels(channels) {
        const updatedChannels = {...channels};
        deselectedChannelsNames.forEach((name) => {
            delete updatedChannels[name];
            removeGraphStyleArray(name);
        });
        style = styler(style_array);
        console.log('channels in removeDeselectedChannels', channels);
        console.log('updatedChannels in removeDeselectedChannels', updatedChannels);
        console.log(Object.is(channels, updatedChannels));
        return updatedChannels;
    }
    if (deselectedChannelsNames.length !== 0) setChannels(removeDeselectedChannels);

    // Manage additional channels
    const newChannelsNames = selectedChannelsNames.filter(x => !currentChannelsNames.includes(x));
    // Load the additional channel(s)
    if (newChannelsNames.length !== 0) newChannelsNames.forEach(fetchTSValues);
}
```

**As you can see, I'm using traces (`console.log`) to trace the changes of `channels` state.** When I deselect a row, `channels` state is indeed changing as shown in following traces:

```
channels in removeDeselectedChannels {demo-temperature-4: {…}}
updatedChannels in removeDeselectedChannels {}
false
```

**And `Object.is` is indeed saying that `channels` updated state is different from previous state. However, `TSChart` component is not rerendered, staying with the display of the previously selected time series.**

**Any clue of what I'm missing?**

Comment: possible cause = state not updating.

Comment: @RohanVeer Can you precise what you mean? As I'm calling `setChannels` with a callback updating the state with a new value?